# Is there a way to upgrade from Dawn 4.0 to Dawn 4.1? Is it worth doing?

Tags: dawn-4.0, dawn-4.1

How to upgrade from Dawn 4.0 to Dawn 4.1? Is it worth doing for test purposes or there were just minor changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth it. They changed a lot of stuff as you can see on the release page: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/dawn-v4.1.0

The procedure that I usually run:

```
# from the eos root folder
rm -rf build
./eosio_build.sh
cd build && sudo make install
```

That's it! If you are using contracts with `account_name` change it to `name` and recompile it, so you can still use them with "account name text" (otherwise you would need to submit the `uint64_t account_name`)

Comment: do they provide a Docker images always up to date?

Comment: rm -rf build -> simply removes build folder? Then you simply build, right? So I understand before you also get the last master? It is not update, but rather delete and install?

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me (starting in eos directory):

```
git pull
git checkout tags/dawn-v4.1.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
./eosio_build.sh
cd build
sudo make install
```

// Restart computer

```
nodeos --resync
```